# What is the meaning of this arguments in this curly brackets

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, python

Pls how do i interprete this argument in this curly brackets marked in red. I'm a beginner in solidity programming and I am have a hard time interpreting this arguments and what does the arguments mean.[image: Mint function]

Comment: Sorry, but which part isn't clear to you? All three arguments? address/account/amount ??

Comment: Yes all three arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had seen other mint functions before. But this one is a bit unusual. However, as far as I can read this all three variables have a clear definition.

Address(0) -> Is null address, and the function is making sure you do not mint coins on null address, as any tokens minted there would be invalid/unusable by default.

Account -> Is a valid address to which you mint new tokens

Ammount -> Is literally the number of tokens you mint. For example, if the ammount=100, then you had just minted 100 of them. (For ERC20 tokens you might need to add 10*18 to that number, but that is another story)